# What is a proper response to こちらこそ?

Tags: meaning, words

When chatting, after こちらこそ is used, I will say はい or どうも. Is this appropriate or should I say nothing and just start chatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's generally the end of it. Someone replying to your 'Thank you' with 'No, thank ***you!***' doesn't require a response.

Comment: I see,  it is I who should say so​/kochirakoso does seem redundant now.